# Print paper template for large object

Tags: objects, 2d, dimensions

I'm designing a backyard playset in Blender and need some help.

I need to print some paper templates to glue to 2"x 12" dimensional lumber to cutout some curved rafter beams. My blend is set to real world scale (1 unit = 1 foot), and I've tried using the Paper Model extension to create a multiple page PDF that I can print and then cut out and piece together to create the paper template but I keep getting the error that an island is too big for the paper (legal—I thought using legal would be a way to cut down on the number of pages that are needed). I'm using the latest build (2.82) but can't see any info on islands or how to alter them. So I have a few questions:

Am I going about this all wrong?

I want digital model to real world object without CNC or 3D printing, the 12ft long template is to be 1:1. The fact that Pepakura Designer crashes while trying to open imported .dae file makes it harder.

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask multiple questions but as separate posts. I suggest editing your question down to just one question (by using the [edit] link below it) and asking the other one separately. Thanks

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, Blender has a [Paper Sheet Exporter](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/import_export/paper_model.html)

Comment: It's hard to edit down Issue #1 to a single question. I will delete Issue #2 and make it it's own question.

Comment: @Leander, I've enable that extension and have used it to poor effect. I can't get a 1:1 scale PDF (multiple page, obviously) to export because of "an island is too big" for the paper size. And I can't find any tutorials or documentation that have helped.